# Can gnupg sign multiple files in parallel?

Tags: authentication, linux, digital-signature, gnupg

I want to sign every file in a directory. I can do so with the following shell command, but it's slow.

**Serial Execution:**

```
find . -type f -printf "Signing %p...\n" -exec gpg --quiet --batch --yes --detach-sig {} \;
```

I have 16 CPU threads and would like to take advantage of these (mostly idle) threads to speed up the signing process. [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) and [Python multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) are behaving oddly, though; when they run `gpg` in parallel, I'm prompted for my PGP key's password multiple times. I'm running `gpg-agent`, so I'd expect to be prompted for my password only once. I also observe intermittent memory allocation errors. The `--lock-once` and `--lock-multiple` CLI options don't seem to change the behavior. Is there some implementation issue with running multiple gpg signing operations in parallel?

Comment: How do you give the passphrase in serial mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question [on the GnuPG mailing list](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2020-November/064342.html), and got this [response](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2020-November/064346.html) from Werner Koch:

> This is all serialized because the gpg-agent does the actual signing.
> There is one gpg-agent per GNUPGHOME.  Thus the easiest solution for you
> is to provide copies of the GNUPGHOME and either set this envvar for
> each process or pass --homedir=decicated-homedir-copy.  You can't use
> links to the same directory because we use lock files.  However, it
> should be possible to sumlink the private-keys-v1.d sub directories.

Working from Werner's answer, I was able to create [a Python script](https://github.com/cqcallaw/www/blob/94f0dbb84fa3908acdd698d7b67071bf4f2a723b/sign.py) which properly signs things using temporary key copies and symlinks:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation, version 3.
This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
General Public License for more details.
You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

This Python script signs all files in a directory in parallel, utilizing all available CPU threads.

Naive use of the multiprocessing module won't work; see https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2020-November/064346.html
"""

import os
import fnmatch
import subprocess
import multiprocessing
import distutils.dir_util
import shutil
import stat
import argparse


def get_fileset(path: str):
    for root, _, files in os.walk(os.path.expanduser(path)):
        for item in fnmatch.filter(files, "*"):
            path = os.path.join(root, item)
            yield path


def create_worker_dirs(working_dir: str, pool_size: int):
    for i in range(1, pool_size + 1):
        dest = os.path.join(working_dir, "ForkPoolWorker-" + str(i))
        print("Generating worker dir", dest)
        os.makedirs(dest, exist_ok=True)
        for f in ['pubring.gpg', 'trustdb.gpg', 'gpg.conf', 'gpa.conf']:
            shutil.copyfile(
                os.path.join(pg_src, f),
                os.path.join(dest, f)
            )
        os.symlink(
            os.path.join(pg_src, 'private-keys-v1.d'),
            os.path.join(dest, 'private-keys-v1.d')
        )

        # fix permissions
        for r, _, f in os.walk(dest):
            os.chmod(r, stat.S_IREAD | stat.S_IWRITE | stat.S_IEXEC)


def sign_file(path: str, working_dir: str):
    worker = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    print(worker, "signing", path)
    worker_working_dir = os.path.join(working_dir, worker)
    r = subprocess.run(['gpg', '--homedir', worker_working_dir,
                        '--quiet', '--batch', '--yes', '--detach-sig', path])
    if r.returncode != 0:
        print("Error signing file", path)
        print(r.stderr)
        return False

    return True


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("dir", help="The directory to sign.", type=str)
    parser.add_argument(
        "pool_size", nargs='?', help="The number of workers to launch. Defaults to the number of available CPU threads.", type=int, default=-1)
    return parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_args()
    files = get_fileset(args.dir)
    pool_size = args.pool_size if args.pool_size != -1 else multiprocessing.cpu_count()

    pg_src = os.path.expanduser('~/.gnupg')
    working_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(
        os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'gnupg-tmp')
    os.makedirs(working_dir, exist_ok=True)
    create_worker_dirs(working_dir, pool_size)

    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=pool_size) as pool:
        results = [pool.apply_async(
            sign_file, (file, working_dir)) for file in files]
        if all([result.get(timeout=10) for result in results]):
            print("Signing completed successfully.")
        else:
            print("Signing error!")

    shutil.rmtree(working_dir)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you see multiple passphrase prompts is because you run multiple programs in parallel.

You will need a way to pass the passphrase to GnuPG. One way is to use `--passphrase-fd`.

Put passphrase into /tmp/pass. Then run:

```
find . -type f |
  parallel 'echo "Signing {}..."; gpg --quiet --batch --yes --passphrase-fd 0 --detach-sig 2 {} </tmp/pass'
```

It seems that if you try using `gpg-agent` in parallel like:

```
eval $(gpg-agent --daemon)
export GPG_AGENT_INFO
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
export SSH_AGENT_PID
find . -type f |
  parallel 'echo "Signing {}..."; gpg --quiet --batch --yes --detach-sig 2 {}'
```

then it will not work. There are [plenty of bug reports](https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=gpg%3A%20signing%20failed%3A%20Cannot%20allocate%20memory&cat=web&pl=ext-ff&language=english&extVersion=1.3.0) indicating that `gpg-agent` will run out of memory if run in parallel.

If you were able to run a `gpg-agent` for each jobslot in parallel, it would be possible to have each jobslot connect to that `gpg-agent`. Unfortunately it seems `gpg-agent` really do not like want to run another instance running in parallel.

Comment: Sure, but using this solution doesn't help me understand why I'm getting multiple password prompts and memory allocation errors, so I'm worried that this solution would suppress behavior that's potentially destructive or insecure.

Comment: I've found that I'm already running gpg-agent; I've updated the question with this information.